# Displaying a test result in an extra EditText

Tags: android, dataformat

I added to my Layout following paragraph:

Layout:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEmissionDetails"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Emission Details"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
    </EditText>
```

In this paragraph I want to show, if the input was a text or Hex, Binary, Decimal, by checking the first ("0") and second (x,b,d) character, and then show that result in the new added layout part.

Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ConsoleActivity extends SerialPortActivity {
    String dataformat;
    EditText mReception;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.console);

        mReception = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextReception);

        EditText Emission;
        Emission = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmission);
        EditText EmissionDetails;
        EmissionDetails = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmissionDetails);

        Emission.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                int i;
                CharSequence t = v.getText();
                char[] text = new char[t.length()];
                for (i=0; i<t.length(); i++) {
                    text[i] = t.charAt(i);
                    dataformat = "text";
                    if (text[0] == '0') {
                        System.out.println("I got a Zero");
                        if (text[1] == 'b') {
                            dataformat = "binary";
                        }
                        if (text[1] == 'd') {
                            dataformat = "decimal";
                        }
                        if (text[1] == 'x') {
                            dataformat = "hex";
                        }
                    }
                    EmissionDetails = "Dataformat " + text[0] + text[1] + " is " + dataformat;
                }
                try {
                    mOutputStream.write(new String(text).getBytes());
                    mOutputStream.write('\n');
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Whatever I try, as suggested by the red lamp in Android-Studio loops sooner or later back to the beginning.

What should I try to adjust to display just the sentence, if hex data are entered (starting with "0x"): "Dataformat 0x is hex"

Comment: So what exactly happens? What does your log say, do you jump into the if?

Answer (score 0):

```
     EmissionDetails.setSingleLine(true) by programatically

    or

    do by xml
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEmissionDetails"
    android:singleline="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Emission Details"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: I added the line in xml and get: Error:(30) No resource identifier found for attribute 'singleline' in package 'android', how to fix that?

Comment: put like this android:singleLine="true"

Comment: I tried android:singleLine="true" and get now: Error:(66, 21) error: local variable EmissionDetails is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(66, 82) error: incompatible types
required: EditText
found:    String